# How to get current play song in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, media-player

I want to get current play song information like some media player program, same the system volume bar. I check some question but not get the right answer. Some one could help me?  I try some solution like BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track or MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong but it alway return null.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use must use FrameworkDispatcher.Update().